# Get column value from Ebean model row/record using variable in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I am trying to return a value from a row returned from an Ebean model in the Play Framework.

I retrieve the row/record with this:

```
public static IntakeEdit findByEditKey(String editKey) {
    return find.where().eq("editkey", editKey).findUnique();
}
```

I am cycling through an array with the column names and want to grab that column value.  I would like to use the name as variable and get the value that way.

Something along the lines of:

```
IntakeEdit intakeEdit = IntakeEdit.findByEditKey(editkey);
String fieldValue = "";
String columnToGet = "projectid"
fieldValue = intakeEdit.getColumnValue(columnToGet);
```

Can this be done? Or is there another method/function I could use?

I appreciate the help!